# Python flask/django object-oriented databases usage

Tags: python

I always use SQL or NoSQL databases in my project and at my job, but now I am asked to use an object-oriented DB. I don't even know for what reason I should do that. Despite this fact, I google for OODBMS in python and can't see any easy way to use this approach. Now I think, that django ORM (and flask sql alchemy) are the simplest way to construct databases.

So, I have two questions:

1. What are the main benefits of using OODBMS instead of, e.x., Django ORM?
2. Is there a simple way to use OODBMS in flask and django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1: OODBMS offers many benefits and to mention a few:

1. It provides greater consistency between the database and the programming language.
2. Doesn’t bother you with object–relational impedance mismatch.
3. It is a more expressive query language and it supports long
   durations/transactions.
4. It is also suitable for advanced database applications.

For question 2:  ZODB is easier and simpler to use, Django is mostly good with ORM only.